# terminating connection because of crash of another server process

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

We are facing this issue with POSTGRES 12.11, only on windows OS, with Linux OS, it works fine,

if the executable that is using the database session crashes, then the entire database goes to recovery mode and restarts, in the Postgres log, we can find the below messages.

```
2022-10-06 17:44:09.210 CEST [8860] LOG:  server process (PID 9980) exited with exit code 0
2022-10-06 17:44:09.210 CEST [8860] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
 
2022-10-06 17:44:09.211 CEST [9992] WARNING:  terminating the connection because of the crash of another server process
 
2022-10-06 17:44:09.211 CEST [9992] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.

2022-10-06 17:44:09.211 CEST [9992] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
```

and then it goes to recovery mode.

any idea or workaround to avoid this issue? and if the Postgres crashes, where does the crash dump gets generated in the windows?

Comment: Did you start PostgreSQL as a service in the background or directly with `pg_ctl`?

Comment: Did you install any non-standard extensions? Is the anti-virus disabled for the Postgres data directory?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I have started the postgres using services.msc

Comment: There is no antivirus on the Windows system

Comment: What were the immediately previous log messages?

Comment: `LOG:  server process (PID 9980) exited with exit code 0` should never happen. This looks like a PostgreSQL bug. You could report it to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks, I have reported to Postgresql.